# MySQL Insert data into table and checking for duplicated values

Tags: mysql

I have a target table **t1** like this *(parent and parent_country are the corresponding id)* with a few thousand entries:

```
id    parent    parent_country  name         type

1     0         0               USA          country
2     0         0               Canada       country
3     1         1               Alabama      state
4     1         1               California   state
5     4         1               Los Angeles  city
...
```

and a source table **t2** like this wth a few thousand entries:

```
loc_text_1    loc_text_2    loc_text_3 

Long Beach    California    USA              
Frankfurt     Hessen        Germany              
Los Angeles   California    USA               
...
```

How can I INSERT the values from **t2** INTO **t1** and furthermore (of course) only those cities, states, and countries which are not already in t1? *(id in t1 is an autoincremented primary key)*

Comment: Are the state names known to be unique?  That would make the queries required to do this somewhat simpler.

Comment: Is the table `t1` empty?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel _I have a target table t1 ... with a few thousand entries:_

Comment: Are there any UNIQUE keys in `t1`? You better just post the crate statements for both tables. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>`

Comment: @Martin No, no column (beside id) is unique. There can duplicates like e.g.: Long Beach in California and Long Beach in New York.

Comment: Surely the parent country for alabama,california and los angeles is 0 USA

Comment: @PaulSpiegel No, t1 is of course not empty.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, all type=countries have parent=0 and parent_country=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE KEY on `(parent, name)` for `t1`.

```
alter table t1 add unique (parent, name);
```

This way you can use `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid inserting duplicates.

Then copy first countries then states and then cities:

```
-- copy countries
insert ignore into t1(parent, parent_country, name, type)
  select distinct 0, 0, loc_text_3, 'country'
  from t2
;

-- copy states
insert ignore into t1(parent, parent_country, name, type)
  select distinct t1.id, t1.id, t2.loc_text_2, 'state'
  from t2
  join t1 on t1.name = t2.loc_text_3
  where t1.type = 'country'
;

-- copy cities
insert ignore into t1(parent, parent_country, name, type)
  select st.id, st.parent, t2.loc_text_1, 'city'
  from t2
  join t1 st on st.name = t2.loc_text_2
  join t1 co on co.name = t2.loc_text_3 and co.id = st.parent
  where st.type = 'state'
    and co.type = 'country'
;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hhpkvgFK6opjFmZwYb7QFv/0

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve the results you want by performing 3 separate `INSERT`s, one for the countries, followed by one for the states and finally one for the cities:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (parent, parent_country, name, type)
SELECT DISTINCT 0, 0, loc_text_3, 'country'
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                  FROM t1
                  WHERE name = t2.loc_text_3 AND type = 'country')

INSERT INTO t1 (parent, parent_country, name, type)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.id, t2.loc_text_2, 'state'
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.name = t2.loc_text_3 AND t1.type = 'country'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                  FROM t1 t1s
                  WHERE parent = t1.id
                    AND name = t2.loc_text_2
                    AND type = 'state')

INSERT INTO t1 (parent, parent_country, name, type)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1c.id, t2.loc_text_1, 'city'
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.name = t2.loc_text_2 AND t1.type = 'state'
JOIN t1 t1c ON t1c.name = t2.loc_text_3 AND t1c.type = 'country' AND t1c.id = t1.parent
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name 
                  FROM t1 t1t
                  WHERE parent = t1.id
                    AND parent_country = t1c.id
                    AND name = t2.loc_text_1
                    AND type = 'city')
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  parent  parent_country  name            type
1   0       0               USA             country
2   0       0               Canada          country
3   1       1               Alabama         state
4   1       1               California      state
5   4       1               Los Angeles     city
6   0       0               Germany         country
7   6       6               Hessen          state
8   4       1               Long Beach      city
9   7       6               Frankfurt       city
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7592b5376b71420dd8f2f8aab3b2c5a)

Comment: You need `DISTICT` everywhere. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=149fcd61a783ddb42ea536c3163b34ed

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Consider that different countries can have cities with the same name. You need more conditions in the NOT EXISTS subqueries.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that was a *lot* more complicated than I originally figured. I think I have it now.

Comment: Looks good now. Though you only need to check `name` and `parent` for duplicates in the subqueries. But redundant conditions don't hurt :-) Actually they can improve performance.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Having slept on it I woke up this morning realising the easier way to do it was to add a unique key and `INSERT IGNORE` and lo and behold... :-)

Comment: That happens to me too. Waking up in the morning with a new idea, thowing away hours of yesterdays work, rewriting it in 10 minutes :-)